# Exact value of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n(n+1)/2}/n$?

Tags: summation

Wolfram is not computing it properly. What is the exact value of
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n(n+1)/2}}{n}?$$ How to avoid imaginary $i$ coming from the exponent?

Comment: Could you edit your post ? The formula is not clear to me. Where is $i$ ?

Comment: $n(n+1)/2$ is always an integer and there will be no $i$.

Comment: often 1/2 in the exponents takes precedence from the companion exponents to whom it should multiply. But wolfram compute / interprete as separate. So -1^(1/2)=i is interpreted.

Comment: I think wolfram is interpreting it as $(-1)^{\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)/n}$ Add more parenthesis.

Comment: Weird. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(+(-1)%5E(n(n%2B1)%2F2))%2Fn+from+n%3D1+to+infinity this still has $i$

Comment: @Sabyasachi. What you see is the numerical value. Look at the coefficient of $i$. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I know. but *why* would an $i$ come in the first place. The individual terms are all real right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The series looks like

$$-\frac11-\frac12+\frac13+\frac14-\frac15-\frac16+\frac17+\frac18-\cdots$$

which may be reduced to

$$-\left (1-\frac13+\frac15-\cdots \right ) - \frac12 \left (1-\frac12+\frac13-\cdots \right )$$

which reduces to

$$-\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac12 \log{2}$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $(-1)^{n(n+1)/2}$ will take two times the value $-1$, two times the value $1$ and so on.

Writing this as two sums should return $\quad-\dfrac{\log 2}2-\dfrac{\pi}4$.

Answer (score 0):

Powers of $-1$ work modulo $2$, so you need to compute
$$n(n+1)/2\mod 2$$
This thing has a period $4$:
$$n=\{1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,\ldots\}\mod 2$$

You can split into two sums and evaluate them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Split the sum into four parts
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}{n}=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Big(-\frac{1}{4n+1}
-\frac{1}{4n+2}
+\frac{1}{4n+3}
+\frac{1}{4n+4}\Big)
$$
Then combine two parts with different signs.
The partial sums up to $m$ can be expressed with the digamma function $\psi$ and the asymptotic series is
$$-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)-\frac{1}{4}\pi+ \frac{1}{4m}-\frac{9}{32m^2}+O(m^{-3})$$

Comment: You can't split the infinite sum into four parts, right? Each of this sum are divergent to $+\infty$.

Comment: @user37238: Thanks, splitting is OK but I cannot have four separate infinite sums. Corrected.